# Cannot run snap applications on MX Linux

Tags: snap, mx-linux

On my MX Linux 21 KDE, I cannot run the snap applications.

This is what happens when I run `snap run authy`:

```
/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-3.scope is not a snap cgroup
```

And this is the output of `snap version`:

```
snap    2.56.2
snapd   2.56.2
series  16
debian  11
kernel  5.15.0-3mx-amd64
```

And this is the output of the command `sudo systemctl status snapd`.

```
● snapd.service - Snap Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-08-02 07:46:11 +06; 23h ago
TriggeredBy: ● snapd.socket
   Main PID: 748 (snapd)
      Tasks: 26 (limit: 18668)
     Memory: 190.0M
        CPU: 18.576s
     CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.service
             └─748 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd

Aug 02 07:46:11 arkabhuiyanhpvictus16 snapd[748]: daemon.go:247: started snapd/2.56.2 (series 16; classic; devmode) debian/11 (amd64) linux/5.15.0-3mx-amd64.
Aug 02 07:46:11 arkabhuiyanhpvictus16 snapd[748]: daemon.go:340: adjusting startup timeout by 1m0s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Aug 02 07:46:11 arkabhuiyanhpvictus16 systemd[1]: Started Snap Daemon.
Aug 02 07:56:53 arkabhuiyanhpvictus16 snapd[748]: devicemgr.go:1927: no NTP sync after 10m0s, trying auto-refresh anyway
Aug 02 07:56:55 arkabhuiyanhpvictus16 snapd[748]: storehelpers.go:722: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "authy", "bare", "core18", "gnome-3-28-1804", "gtk-common-themes", "snapd"
Aug 02 07:56:55 arkabhuiyanhpvictus16 snapd[748]: autorefresh.go:539: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
Aug 03 03:46:31 arkabhuiyanhpvictus16 snapd[748]: storehelpers.go:722: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "authy", "bare", "core18", "gnome-3-28-1804", "gtk-common-themes", "snapd"
Aug 03 03:46:31 arkabhuiyanhpvictus16 snapd[748]: autorefresh.go:539: auto-refresh: all snaps are up-to-date
Aug 03 05:20:06 arkabhuiyanhpvictus16 snapd[748]: api_snaps.go:317: Installing snap "core" revision unset
Aug 03 05:20:41 arkabhuiyanhpvictus16 snapd[748]: api_snaps.go:317: Installing snap "mysql-workbench-community" revision unset
```

You can see that I have the latest stable kernel installed on my system. So what might be the issue, and how can I resolve it?

Full systemctl status: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/HZtmNBw3r3/

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/HZtmNBw3r3/

Comment: Please run `SNAPD_DEBUG=1 snap run authy` and paste the output

Comment: @don_aman, here is the pastebin link: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/BBRBqtzwxF/

Comment: looks like a dbus problem, please run `dpkg -l 'dbus*'`

Comment: This is the output: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/sfsCtk2b55/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138307/discussion-on-question-by-lone-wolf-cannot-run-snap-applications-on-mx-linux).

Comment: Please add all relevant information and pastebin links to the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MX Linux too, and had the same problem for some Snaps. For me, the solution was to "correct" the environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` to this:

`export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/bus"`

[Source](https://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/snap-problem-solving.html)